# When using ifconfig to see my Mac address, which one is for connecting to a wireless network?

Tags: networking, authentication, ifconfig

I am using an older laptop that I converted from windows xp to ubuntu 14.04, so my question is about what Hardware address should I use to connect to my college network? The reason I ask is because instead of being given a password to connect to the network, we are told to record the mac address and wait for approval. So I know that when I use `ifconfig` I am given two mac addresses, one under the `eth0` category and the other under the `wlan` category. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLAN stands for Wireless Local Area Network, as opposed to `eth0`, which stands for ethernet, which is a physical network cable.

It's probably `wlan0`, as it's the first WiFi card (your machine likely only has one).

Answer (score 0):

It is your `wlan` mac address...

Comment: I had figured, and thanks for clearing that up for me! :)